# (CLOSED) Generation has thrown an exception: list index out of range problem

Tags: armature, rigify

[image: screenshot]

So tried to generate rig for my model, and I encounter this problem

```
  File "..<cut>..\addons\rigify\rigs\limbs\leg.py", line 52, in find_org_bones
    for b in self.get_bone(bones.main[2]).bone.children:
IndexError: list index out of range
Error: Generation has thrown an exception: list index out of range
```

I don't know how to fix it, but I know that this problem pops out when you use metarig (i used basic human, not human), and you didn't delete all bones

I cannot give you the log, because I made this figure not in one session. Also, I undo the generating rig process, so if you need to generate rig to see the problem just generate it.

Here is the [blend file](https://www.mediafire.com/file/atrr8tm7y1iknbp/byu.blend/file).

Comment: You will probably need to include more info of your own. The addon you're using doesn't come packed with the .blend file. Post screenshots of the issue, what you've tried already, some before and afters, post the full stack trace error from the console, etc.

Comment: Your metarig has no foot bones. And the head and neck bones are missing. That's bad. Rigify uses so-called *Rig Types*. This is a chain/bunch of bones that form a leg, arm, pawn, or finger. [A leg needs 5 bones](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/limbs.html#limbs-leg). That's the problem. Maybe start over with a fresh meta rig because the next error will be the arms. If you want to create a new leg, edit the rig & delete the leg bones. Then use menu *Rigify > Add Metarig Sample* & choose *Rig Type* = *limb.leg* to create a new leg with all required bones.